# ¿Cómo eliminar imágenes guardadas en el disco duro con python y django'

Tags: python, django, django-models

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una página web con [python](/questions/tagged/python) y [django](/questions/tagged/django), tengo una tabla noticias la cual tiene como campos: titulo, subtitulo, cuerpo de la noticia e imagen; Esta imagen es cargada a travéz del navegador y guardada en el el disco duro del servidor. Al eliminar el registro de la base de datos se me elimina el registro pero la imagen sigue alojada en el disco duro este el código que uso para la eliminación.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    del_noticia = noticia.objects.get(id=id_noticia)

    try:
        del_noticia.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/lista_noticias')
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/lista_noticias')
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect ('/')
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo eliminar la imagen del disco duro.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para remover las imágenes del sistema, lo mas adecuado es usar el modulo de `os` que viene en python, de esta forma:

```
import os
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    try:
        noticia = noticia.objects.get(id=id_noticia)
        if os.path.exists(noticia.imagen._get_path()) and os.path.isfile(noticia.imagen._get_path()):
            os.remove(noticia.imagen._get_path())
        noticia.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/lista_noticias')
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/lista_noticias')
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect ('/')
```

Esta seria una forma de hacerlo, ahora, esto solo servirá al momento de eliminar por medio de esta vista, si fuera otra vista tendrías que hacer lo mismo, por lo que suelo recomendar usar las señales (signals) de django para estos casos.

Comment: Wow, Muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: @DanielCeron si te sirvió la respuesta, no olvides marcarla como respondida, para así cerrar la pregunta